# Button does not respond to touches

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, button

In my app there is a background on top of the window:

```
UIImageView *mybg = [[UIImageView alloc]
                     initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_large.png"]];
[window addSubview:mybg];
```

then a button in top of the background:

```
UIButton *infoButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] retain];
infoButton.frame = CGRectMake(280,420,20,20);

[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfoPanel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[window addSubview:infoButton];
[infoButton release];
```

then a scrollview inside a navigation controller, those added to the window on the top:

```
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
navController.viewControllers = [[NSArray arrayWithObject:dashboardViewController] retain];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
myScrollView.opaque=NO;
myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
dashboardViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

the scrollview respond to touches as it should, but the infoButton that added before in the top of the background doesn't. I added the infoButton to the top of the bg, to be stable and not scroll with scrollview.

How can I make the button respond to touches, as well as the scrollview together with it?

Comment: What happens if you don't add the navController? What happens if you don't have the button and the navController overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

U are adding UINavigationController.view on the top of button thats why it is not respoiding, Try placing the code [window addSubview:infoButton]; after [window addSubview:navController.view];.

Comment: doing that the button stays on top of nav controller when the controller push another view.

Comment: Since you are adding button to window it will not cause problem... otherwise just add [window bringSubviewToFront:infoButton] after adding view controller.